# QtCreator how do I NOT step into Qt library source?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm looking for advice on QtCreator debugging.
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 64bit and QtCreator 4.12.4. Qt version 5.12.4.
My issue is that when I run my code in debug mode, the debugger steps into and breaks inside Qt source library code. My question is how do I prevent stopping at breakpoints within Qt source library code because I have no interest in Qt source outside of my linking to the library.
I just want to be able to set breakpoints within my own code but QtCreator debug breaks within Qt library source and this is very distracting, making the debugger unusable.
Thanks in advance for your advice!
Phil

Comment: For the most developers it is harder to step in Qt source code as there no debug symbols provided. People should first enable debugging Qt source code explicitly. And there breakpoints in Qt code already set? Also, strange. I would just don't do Step In (in Qt functions) which is F11 assignment in standard Qt Creator. Mind you have Shift-F11 to go up. And just do F10 over the Qt call and you will never be tracing the library itself. Or was it some crash situation inside Qt code? Then the reason must be up call stack in your code to fix.

Comment: Thanks Alexander V for responding. It turns out that I have the opposite problem, namely I don't want to step into Qt code and apparently I am. This is rendering the debugger useless since I apparently keep hitting breakpoints in the Qt code. My application works fine when not debugging. Thanks, Phil

Comment: And the debugger steps into Qt code even though I use F5 or F10. Thanks

Comment: The debugger keeps stopping at line 384 in qfactoryloader.cpp when hitting F10 in: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv); at QApplication app....

Comment: You should start the debugging with F5 unless you want to go through the main() from start. Put a breakpoint in your code by locating it / F9 and then do F5 so it runs until it hits the breakpoint. Normally that works. Except if you have a problem with Qt code right away and maybe it wants to show you. You said you already have breakpoints in Qt code? Try to erase all breakpoints first then,

Comment: It appears that I found my answer. It looks like I had a bunch of breakpoints set that I didn't want. I told QCreator to remove all breakpoints then put in the ones I wanted and now the behavior is as expected. Thanks again! Phil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid entering library's source files while debugging in Qt Creator with gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448426/how-to-avoid-entering-librarys-source-files-while-debugging-in-qt-creator-with)