# Displaying each assembly instruction executed in gdb

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, freebsd

I currently have a tricky bug that occurs in a place where I don't have access to source or symbols, i.e. I can see the instruction and its address where the crash occurs, but that's about it. **What I'd like to do is have `gdb` run without requiring interaction and display every instruction as it does so**, but I've yet to find a way to do it.

What I'm hoping to achieve is something like this:

```
(gdb) /* some command */
0x2818a7c0: push   %ebp
0x2818a7c1: mov    %esp,%ebp
0x2818a7c3: push   %ebx
0x2818a7c4: sub    $0x4,%esp
...
0x28563622: mov    %esi,0x0(%eax)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

What I've been doing is setting up a display for the program counter, like so:

```
(gdb) display/i $pc
```

And then running through the code with `stepi`:

```
(gdb) stepi
1: x/i $pc  0x2818a7c0: push   %ebp
```

However, the crash is hundreds or thousands of instructions away, and I'd like a way to see each one (together, if preferable), without having to hit "enter" that many times. Also, if I were to do it manually, I'd see a `(gdb)` prompt between each instruction, which is less than desirable.

One route I've briefly looked into is [scripting](http://johnnyjacob.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/gdb-scripting-short-article-for-internal-magazine/), but my only thought is to setup at `main()`, have it display and another break (for the next instruction), and then continue, but then I can't use `commands` within a `commands` block, so it wouldn't work the way I'm imagining it.

In case it matters, I'm working on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following should do what you asked for:

```
# not strictly required, but you'll likely want the log anyway
(gdb) set logging on

# ask gdb to not stop every screen-full
(gdb) set height 0

(gdb) while 1
 > x/i $pc
 > stepi
 > end
```

However, this approach to debugging will likely prove futile: there are simply *too many* instructions executed even in most trivial programs.

A better approach might be to run the program until crash, attempt to understand what current function is doing and who calls it, and setting breakpoints appropriately.

On x86, you can often deduce function boundaries even in fully stripped executable.

Another thing you'll want to look at is `strace/truss` output, so you can see what system calls immediately precede the crash point.

Comment: How to set that log to another file than gdb.txt? Can I set file name by time stamp?

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom  Yes, you can. Please ask this question as a real question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 6):

**Python scripting**

This will give more flexibility than GDB scripting to achieve your crazy ideas.

The main problem here, just like with GDB scripts, is that this will likely be too slow for most applications without target hardware support, e.g.: a C hello world takes 1 minute for only 18k instructions.

gdb.py

```
class TraceAsm(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            'trace-asm',
            gdb.COMMAND_BREAKPOINTS,
            gdb.COMPLETE_NONE,
            False
        )
    def invoke(self, argument, from_tty):
        argv = gdb.string_to_argv(argument)
        if argv:
            gdb.write('Does not take any arguments.\n')
        else:
            done = False
            thread = gdb.inferiors()[0].threads()[0]
            last_path = None
            last_line = None
            with open('trace.tmp', 'w') as f:
                while thread.is_valid():
                    frame = gdb.selected_frame()
                    sal = frame.find_sal()
                    symtab = sal.symtab
                    if symtab:
                        path = symtab.fullname()
                        line = sal.line
                    else:
                        path = None
                        line = None
                    if path != last_path:
                        f.write("path {}{}".format(path, os.linesep))
                        last_path = path
                    if line != last_line:
                        f.write("line {}{}".format(line, os.linesep))
                        last_line = line
                    pc = frame.pc()
                    f.write("{} {} {}".format(hex(pc), frame.architecture().disassemble(pc)[0]['asm'], os.linesep))
                    gdb.execute('si', to_string=True)
TraceAsm()
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/dotfiles/blob/109ae39f256e5ed149480d9cd963c03d95600f23/home/.gdbinit.py#L199).

main.S

```
global _start
_start:
    ; Write.
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, hello_world
    mov rdx, hello_world_len
    syscall

    ; Exit.
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

hello_world db "hello world", 10
hello_world_len equ $ - hello_world
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-assembly-cheat/blob/c83f548fb4ada1a14e7b209b676586905525a069/x86-64/gas/linux/hello_world.S).

Assemble and run:

```
as -o main.o main.S
ld -o main.out main.o
gdb -nh -batch -ex 'source ~/test/gdb.py' -ex 'starti' -ex 'trace-asm' ./main.out
cat trace.tmp
```

Output:

```
0x401000 mov    $0x1,%rax 
0x401007 mov    $0x1,%rdi 
0x40100e mov    $0x402000,%rsi 
0x401015 mov    $0xc,%rdx 
0x40101c syscall  
0x40101e mov    $0x3c,%rax 
0x401025 mov    $0x0,%rdi 
0x40102c syscall
```

**QEMU emulation**

Edit: `-d in_asm` alone shows only translation chunks, so if a chunk gets executed multiple times, it won't show multiple times. There are some extra flags that make it more accurate, see: [What instructions does qemu trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847254/what-instructions-does-qemu-trace/64876198#64876198) QEMU's `exec_tb` trace backend might however do it: [How to use QEMU's simple trace backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149446/how-to-use-qemus-simple-trace-backend/46497873#46497873)

This performed much faster than the GDB python solution, the C hello works runs instantaneously! However, the log was only 10k instructions long instead of 18k on the same executable, so it must be skipping something that normally gets run TODO understand.

E.g. in user mode simulation:

```
qemu-x86_64 -d in_asm ./main.out
```

Output:

```
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
----------------
IN: 
0x0000000000401000:  mov    $0x1,%rax
0x0000000000401007:  mov    $0x1,%rdi
0x000000000040100e:  mov    $0x402000,%rsi
0x0000000000401015:  mov    $0xc,%rdx
0x000000000040101c:  syscall 

hello world
----------------
IN: 
0x000000000040101e:  mov    $0x3c,%rax
0x0000000000401025:  mov    $0x0,%rdi
0x000000000040102c:  syscall
```

[See also](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/79b35fb395f9f7f7621609186931408fe2f79881#tracing).

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GDB 8.2, QEMU 2.12.0.

Comment: This looks very interesting and I was wondering if you can address how to execute this code. Is there a special gdb module that needs to be imported?

Comment: @ttb hi, you just source it like a regular GDB script, see updated answer. The binding is built into GDB, no need to install anything extra. I also had some fun with QEMU while reviewing this and added to answer.

Comment: @ Ciro Santilli 新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 Why your gdb.py is better that the simple script Employed Russian put ? Thanks

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom not for the exact use case, the advantage is mostly the flexibility it provides, e.g. you could trivially hack it to break at a given instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031930/how-to-break-on-instruction-with-a-specific-opcode-in-gdb/31249378#31249378 or turn on off parts of the print depending on what you want to see (a full instruction trace will be too slow for anything but the most trivial programs)

Answer (score 2):

1. Dissassemble the binary separately (e.g. using objdump) and consult the listing while debugging
2. Use [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) and its debugger. Much better experience IMO.

(disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays)

Comment: I've updated my question to note that I'm currently working on FreeBSD, which I believe rules out #2?

Comment: Ah yes, currently IDA does not support debugging FreeBSD binaries. However, you can still use it as a disassembler (on Windows/Wine or by using Linux support on FreeBSD) - it's much better than looking at the dead listing.