# How to let GDB continue until the program enters another function?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

Say I am in A() and A() calls B(). I just entered A() and I want the program to run until I am in B(). It doesn't have to be a specific function B(). I just want my program to pause whenever it enters a new function. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a nice solution in form of setting a breakpoint on `call` instruction, but [as this answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032055/13767) there is no way to do that.

I think, the easiest solution would be to set that breakpoints manually or try to [write a script in Python](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548) which finds function calls in the currect function listing and sets desired breakpoints.

Comment: I wrote the opcode detection script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31249378/895245 but for this specific case there is a more efficient solution with `rbreak .`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31249717/895245

Answer (score 3):

For calls, as mentioned at: [List of all function calls made in an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549693/gdb-list-of-all-function-calls-made-in-an-application) :

```
set confirm off
rbreak .
```

`rbreak` sets a breakpoint for every function that matches a given regular expression, `.` matches all functions.

This command might take a while to run for a large executable with lots of functions. But once it finishes, runtime will be efficient.

The exit is trickier, since we can't know at compile time where we will land: [How to set a breakpoint in GDB where the function returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649468/setting-breakpoint-in-gdb-where-the-function-returns)

At [How to break on instruction with a specific opcode in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031930/how-to-break-on-instruction-with-a-specific-opcode-in-gdb/14032055#14032055) I also provided a script that single steps until a desired instruction is found, which you could use to find `callq`. That one has the advantage of not making you wait on a large executable, but execution will be very slow, so the target can't be very far away.