# How to change the Python Interpreter that gdb uses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdb

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, where python3 is a default system package.

I want to debug Python2.7 programs with gdb, but I seem to encounter this issue:

When i'm in gdb, using the `py` command puts me in an interpreter, so i ran these commands in the interpreter:

First I check the interpreter version:

```
(gdb) py
>import sys
>print(sys.version)
>end
3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

Then I check what interpreter executable is being used

```
(gdb) py
>import sys
>print(sys.executable)
>end
/usr/bin/python
(gdb)
```

Then in bash, I check the interpreter:

```
12:34]hostname ~ $ls -l /usr/bin/python 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 21  2013 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

So although gdb says it's using my 2.7 interpreter, it's actually using another one. I need a 2.7 interpreter to be able to use it with the python specific extensions that the ubuntu package 'python2.7-dbg' provides, because as far as i know there's no such package for python 3.4 yet, and even if there was, the programs that i want to debug run python 2.7

My question is how do i make it use the interpreter I want?

**[EDIT]**
**Do not uninstall python3** btw. I did it on ubuntu 14.04 and it wrecked my system. Couldn't manage to get it up again. I'm currently using it with no window-manager (it's cool and 1337), but you get the idea.

Comment: why is python 3 the default?

Comment: i guess because Ubuntu says so..? i haven't read much into it, but https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3  this says a lot of scripts were ported to python 3 (though not all). In any case my gdb install (or compile or whatever) coupled with python3

Comment: Related issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1241668

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> So although gdb says it's using my 2.7 interpreter

GDB doesn't say that. It says it's using 3.4.0, and that interpreter is *linked into* GDB, in the form of `libpython3.4.a` or `libpython3.4.so`.

Since there is no actual Python binary involved, the (minor) bug here is that `sys.executable`  returns `/usr/bin/python`. It would possibly be better for it to return `/usr/bin/gdb` instead.

> I need a 2.7 interpreter

In that case, you'll have to rebuild `gdb` from source, after configuring it with appropriate `--with-python` value.

Comment: can I know how my gdb is bullt? (I mean with what options?)

Comment: @ChanKim: To see which version of the Python library is linked to your installed GDB, try `ldd $(which gdb) | grep python`

Comment: @kevinarpe The method you propose works only if gdb is linked dynamically against libpython. The method OP used (`print(sys.version)`) works *always*.

Comment: Crazy... I have a copy of GDB distributed with JetBrains CLion, and I cannot figure out which Python it is linked against using ldd -- does not show libpython.  However, if using GDB from JetBrains CLion and I run commands  `python import sys` then `python print(sys.version)`, I see the Python interpreter is v2 not v3.

Comment: This answer is the best as far I know. However there are couple things to mention; first give this link http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gdb.html, where you can find an step by step, how to build a custom GDB and the sources. Second is point out that when you build GDB, by default, it uses references to python2 and you must specify python version only if you want use python3.
Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

No need to rebuild gdb.

Just invoke it differently:

```
gdb -ex run --args /usr/bin/python2 test.py
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$ apt-get -qq update
$ apt-get install gdb python2.7-dbg python3-all-dbg
$ gdb -ex r -ex quit --args python2 -c "import sys ; print(sys.version)" # Py2.7
$ gdb -ex r -ex quit --args python3 -c "import sys ; print(sys.version)" # Py3.6
```

Comment: This is just running the two python interpreters in gdb.

It has nothing to do with the version of python that gdb has bundled.