# Is there a way to log executed instruction between two breakpoints in GDB?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug a program and it will be beneficial for me to compare the instruction traces of two different executions. However, I am only interested to see the executed instructions between 2 breakpoints. Can I generate an instruction trace between two breakpoints and save it in a file?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/8841373/72178