# gdb "skip" command cannot skip libc++ header file

Tags: c++, gdb, libc++

I have read [Tell gdb to skip standard files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676241/tell-gdb-to-skip-standard-files) ,but it not work in libc++ header file like "memory".

Example:

```cpp
// main.cc
#include <memory>
int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>(10);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```sh
clang++ -g -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++14 main.cc
```

Then start gdb and skip the memory file:

```sh
(gdb) skip -file /usr/include/c++/v1/memory
```

After that,you can **still** `step` into `std::make_unique()` function, why is that? (I use gdb-8.3.1-release.)

2020.1.15:
I can confirm the path is correct,because I copy the path from gdb frame.

I also try add the below skip rules, still not work.(The first two rules work in libstdc++.)

```sh
skip -rfu std::.*
skip -rfu std::.*::.*
skip -gfu /usr/include/c++/v1/*
```

I have tried debug gdb-8.3.1 itself,and find that gdb return from `gdb/infrun.c:6365` because `in_solib_dynsym_resolve_code()` return `1`.while in the `libc++` version of `std::make_unique` gdb get into `gdb/infrun.c:6569` and call into `function_name_is_marked_for_skip()`.

`function_name_is_marked_for_skip()` is the place gdb check skip rules.

So,it looks like a fresh gdb issue out of [gdb bug list](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=SUSPENDED&bug_status=WAITING&bug_status=REOPENED&field0-0-0=product&no_redirect=1&order=product%2Cbug_status%2Cpriority%2Cassigned_to%2Cbug_id&query_format=advanced&type0-0-0=substring&value0-0-0=gdb).

Comment: And when you skip into `std::make_unique`, does it show the current file is the one you excluded?

Comment: Yes,I copy the path from the gdb frame.