# Stepping into Specific Function in GDB

Tags: debugging, automation, gdb, visual-studio-debugging, step-into

Does GDB support Stepping into a *Specific* function, say either `f` or `g`, on lines containing expressions of nested function calls such as

```
f(g());
```

similar to [what Visual Studio 2010 support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ad07721.aspx). Maybe a GDB script is the solution?

Comment: The gdb-approach is a bit different. Instead of stepping into a specific function you can define skips. If you input `skip g()` gdb will execute `g()` without stepping into it and step into `f`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does GDB support Stepping into a Specific function

No. If you want to step into `g`, a simple `step` should do it. If you want to step into `f`, do `step`, `finish`, `step`.

You are welcome to file a feature request in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb), though I doubt `Step into Specific` can be reasonably implemented in a CLI debugger.

Answer (score 17):

The command `advance` from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133403/2708138 is useful. You can combine that command with `print f` to get the type of `f` in the current context beforehand.

Furthermore, I have already mentioned in the comment to your question that you can `skip` the function `g` if you never want to step through it.

See the gdb-help for the keywords `advance`, `print` and `skip`.

At least the `skip`-feature is quite new. So maybe, it was not available at the time when [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50617/employed-russian) gave his answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer! `skip` is designed to solve the exact problem that the question describes. `step` and `finish` alternative gets tedious and tiring very soon! I'll add a bounty for this answer so that it gets more attention and saves people some time.

Comment: Is there any update to this? skip command is useful but not the solution. If there is a line of code with many overridden operators and whatnot, it's tedious to get to the point you want to be at. Why not directly specify the function you're interested in stepping into?