# GDB C++ How to Stop Stepping Inside Standard Libraries

Tags: c++, gdb

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432347/stop-gdb-from-stepping-through-glibc-functions) post briefly discusses the same trouble I am facing. Essentially, is there a default setting or a hack for gdb to stop stepping inside every single glib library and only step inside user files? I know I can call `finish` each time it steps inside one but it's some wasted keystrokes I'd rather avoid.

It's already annoying as it is to deal with g++'s output. If this exhibitionism cannot be stopped, are there good alternatives to these gnu tools? I do hear good things about eclipse, but I'm just a student looking for quick and dirty fixes with minimal effort.

Comment: why is the keystroke "wasted" when it does what you want?

Comment: I don't want it to step inside glib files. Hence, "wasted".

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/5676241/72178.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tell gdb to skip standard files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676241/tell-gdb-to-skip-standard-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have GDB 7.12.1 or above you can add the following to your `~/.gdbinit` file:

```
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*/*
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*
```

Double check that these are in fact the right places for those libs. This answer comes from [here](https://reversed.top/2016-05-26/skipping-standard-library-in-gdb/).

**Some options without editing gdb init**

If you want to "step over" a line (like `std::vector<int> a;`) without stepping into it, you can use `next`.

If you have a situation like `int b = is_negative(a[0])` and you want to stop in `is_negative` you have a few options:

1. Step into the `a[0]` function then use `finish` to step out again.
2. Use `tbreak is_negative` to create a temporary breakpoint on the `is_negative` function then use `next` to step which will break on the breakpoint.

2 is faster in the case where you have something with many sub calls in a function like:

```
is_negative(a[b.at(2)] * c[3]);
```

Comment: That is a nice trick! However, it still doesn't answer my question. In fact, one could even argue that `tbreak function` is worse for a sloth like me as oppose to using a single `finish`

Comment: I mean the answer to the question "can i avoid stepping into stdlib with GDB" is probably just "no". These are some alternatives.

Comment: You can have a look at something like [this](https://reversed.top/2016-05-26/skipping-standard-library-in-gdb/)  but it is not so easy to set up compared with writing finish a couple of times.

Comment: That is what I was after. Put it in your answer, I will vote it now since implementing this would take time.

Comment: Edit: it works, I am finally free from this curse! I use gdb version 9.1 so the simple solution at the end does the trick